# X & Y are continuous random variables. X takes on values between 0 & 2 while Y takes on values between 0 & 1. Distribution of fx|y(x|0.5)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

I calculated the marginal fy(y) & then calculated the conditional. But the answer is 1/2 for 1/2<x<1 & 3/2 for 1<x<3/2.

My Calculation:

[image]

Comment: Yes,, that is the answer.$$f_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid 0.5)=\tfrac 12\mathbf 1_{0.5\leqslant x\lt 1}+\tfrac{3}{2}\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant x\lt 1.5}$$What was your concern?  You should include what calculations you made, so that the error can be spotted.

Comment: I have included my calculation. I am not able to get where am I going wrong.

Comment: The appearance of $x$ in the function of $f_{Y}(y)$ is a clue as to where the error lies.  There should be no reference to $x$ after integrating it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the integration.   You must integrate over all $x$ supported for a given $y$ ... often called "integrating out $x$".   The result, a monovariate function of $y$, is therefore not going to be partitioned over the value of $x$.

$$\begin{align}f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)&=\tfrac 12\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant x\lt 1}+\tfrac 32\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant x\leqslant 2-y\leqslant 2}\\[3ex]f_{\small Y}(y)&=\left(\int_y^1\tfrac 12\,\mathrm d x+\int_1^{2-y}\tfrac 32\,\mathrm d x\right)\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant 1}\\[1ex]&=2(1-y)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant 1}\\[3ex]f_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid 1/2)&=\dfrac{f_{\small X,Y}(x,1/2)}{f_{\small Y}(1/2)}\\[1ex]&=\tfrac 12\mathbf 1_{1/2\leqslant x\lt 1}+\tfrac{3}{2}\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant x\lt 3/2}\\[1ex]&\end{align}$$

Comment: I understood my error.  Marginal will be constant for a given value while I split them wrongly. Thanks.